# Error using MODIS HDF files in ArcMap Raster Calculator

Tags: arcgis, arcmap, hdf

I have downloaded several HDF files from the [MODIS](http://(ftp://ftp.ntsg.umt.edu/pub/MODIS/NTSG_Products/MOD16/)) database. 
According to the documentation, the layers have to be multiplied by `0.1` to obtain the real values.

I get an error when I put the name of the HDF-layer in the Raster Calculator, however it does work when I export it as a new raster before. But after multiplication with `0.1`, I still **do not** get a continuous scale image but only black and white areas. I excluded the seven highest values as indicated in the documentation, but still no change.

Another way of getting the MODIS files is to use the [respective toolbox](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=2c2930e260f24427a35e6f5bf792adc4). Data imported with this tool does show up correctly, but I cannot import most of it even though it is available under the link indicated above:

- Failed to execute (CreateCustomGeoTransformation)
- Failed to execute (ImportEvapotranspiration)

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: Fixed the formatting of the links and added a list rather than a quotes.

Comment: You may not be aware but there is a [gis.se] Stack Exchange with MANY ArcGIS for Desktop questions already answered.